# Get a JSON object based on one of its values

Tags: c#, json, object, json.net

Basically I have this JSON and I have to get the "Id" based on the "Userid"

```
[
  {
    "Userid": 2,
    "Id": 99999
  },
  {
    "Userid": 4,
    "Id": 55555
  }
]
```

I need to select the JSON object based on the "Userid".

How would I do that?

I used this thread: [Json.Net Select Object based on a value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18926781/json-net-select-object-based-on-a-value)

The solution there was:

```
string json = @"
{
    wvw_matches: [
        {
            wvw_match_id: ""1-4"",
            red_world_id: 1011,
            blue_world_id: 1003,
            green_world_id: 1002,
            start_time: ""2013-09-14T01:00:00Z"",
            end_time: ""2013-09-21T01:00:00Z""
        },
        {
            wvw_match_id: ""1-2"",
            red_world_id: 1017,
            blue_world_id: 1021,
            green_world_id: 1009,
            start_time: ""2013-09-14T01:00:00Z"",
            end_time: ""2013-09-21T01:00:00Z""
        }
    ]
}";

string matchIdToFind = "1-2";
JObject jo = JObject.Parse(json);

JObject match = jo["wvw_matches"].Values<JObject>()
    .Where(m => m["wvw_match_id"].Value<string>() == matchIdToFind)
    .FirstOrDefault();

if (match != null)
{
    foreach (JProperty prop in match.Properties())
    {
        Console.WriteLine(prop.Name + ": " + prop.Value);
    }
}
```

But since mine doesn't have a "wvw_matches" (no idea what to call it), I don't understand how I would use it in my situation.

Comment: `jo.Values<JObject>().Where(m => m["Userid"].Value<string>() == matchIdToFind).FirstOrDefault();`?

Comment: `var str = File.ReadAllText("E:/User.json");
            string json = $"{str}";
            JObject jo = JObject.Parse(json);
            string matchIdToFind = "1";
            JObject match = jo.Values<JObject>().Where(m => m["Userid"].Value<string>() == matchIdToFind).FirstOrDefault();

            if (match != null)
            {
                foreach (JProperty prop in match.Properties())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(prop.Name + ": " + prop.Value);
                }
            }` this throws the error:

Comment: `string json = $"{str}";`? What steps did you take to figure out what `File.ReadAllText()` returns?

Comment: ;p Error here: "Error reading JObject from JsonReader. Current JsonReader item is not an object: StartArray. Path '', line 1, position 1."

Comment: `File.ReadAllText()` returns the json.

Comment: I fixed it thanks @CSerg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you can do it.

```
public class Sample
{
    public string Userid { get; set; }
    public string Id { get; set; }
}


public static void Main(string[] args)
{
        using (var stream = new StreamReader("sample.json"))
        {

            var sampleArray = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Sample[]>(stream.ReadToEnd());

            foreach (var users in sampleArray)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Userid: {0}", users.Userid);
                Console.WriteLine("Id: {0}", users.Id);
            }
        }

        Console.Read();
}
```

You need to map your JSON response to a class. And as you have an array you need

`var sampleArray = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Sample[]>(stream.ReadToEnd());`

Hope it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you don't have tons of records, create a class to hold the object that the JSON represents.

```
public class JsonData //name this something relevant to your data.
{
    public int Userid { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public static JsonData[] Deserialize(string jsonString)
    {
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonData[]>(jsonString);
    }
}
```

Then just use a linq expression to query the array.

```
jsonArray.Where(j => j.Userid == <your value>).Select(j => j.Id);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since I wrote the example you refer to, here it is updated to use your JSON instead.

```
string json = @"
[
  {
    ""Userid"": 2,
    ""Id"": 99999
  },
  {
    ""Userid"": 4,
    ""Id"": 55555
  }
]";

string userIdToFind = "4";

JArray ja = JArray.Parse(json);

JObject match = ja.Children<JObject>()
    .FirstOrDefault(m => m["Userid"].Value<string>() == userIdToFind);

if (match != null)
{
    foreach (JProperty prop in match.Properties())
    {
        Console.WriteLine(prop.Name + ": " + prop.Value);
    }
}
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/vpZpSS

The difference is that your JSON *is* an array, whereas the JSON in the original example was an object with a property *containing* an array.